# Can I store javascript class objects in indexed database?

Tags: javascript, class, indexeddb

I created a class called Book with a constructor and some methods.

```
class Book {
    constructor(title, author) {
        this.title = title;
        this.author = author;
    }

    displayInfo() {
        console.log(`Title: ${this.title}, Author: ${this.author}`);
    }
}
```

Then I created a bunch of Book objects and I put them in an array called Library.

```
const book1 = new Book('Hobbit', 'JRR Tolkien');
const book2 = new Book('Mistborn', 'Brandon Sanderson');

let library = [];
library.push(book1);
library.push(book2);

console.log(library);
library.forEach(book => book.displayInfo());
```

Then I stored this Library array in indexeddb.

```
if (!window.indexedDB) {
    window.alert("IndexedDB doesn't work");
}

let request = indexedDB.open("Database", 1);
let db, tx, store;
request.onupgradeneeded = function(e) {
let db = request.result;
let store = db.createObjectStore('Collection', { keyPath: 'type' });
};
request.onerror = function(e) {
    console.log('error ' + e.target.errorCode);
};
request.onsuccess = function(e) {
    db = request.result;
    tx = db.transaction('Collection', 'readwrite');
    store = tx.objectStore('Collection');

    db.onerror = function(e) {
        console.log('error ' + e.target.errorCode);
    };
    console.log('adding do collection db');
    store.put({ type: 'library', data: library });

    tx.oncomplete = function() {
        db.close();
    };
};
```

Now I would like to restore this array after every page refresh and run Book methods on objects stored in the array. But when I restored data I saw that my Book objects are no longer Book objects, just regular objects so I can't use Book methods on them.

```
if (!window.indexedDB) {
    window.alert("IndexedDB doesn't work");
}

let request = indexedDB.open("Database", 1);
let db, tx, store;
request.onupgradeneeded = function(e) {
    console.log('upgrading');
    let db = request.result;
    let store = db.createObjectStore('Collection', { keyPath: 'type' });
};
request.onerror = function(e) { console.log('error ' + e.target.errorCode); };
request.onsuccess = function(e) {
    console.log('success');
    db = request.result;
    tx = db.transaction('Collection', 'readwrite');
    store = tx.objectStore('Collection');

    db.onerror = function(e) { console.log('error ' + e.target.errorCode); };

    let retrievedData = store.get('library');

    retrievedData.onsuccess = function(e) {
        if (retrievedData.result) console.log(retrievedData);
        if (retrievedData.result) library = retrievedData.result.data;

        console.log(library);
        library.forEach(book => book.displayInfo());
    }

    tx.oncomplete = function() {
        db.close();
    };
};
```

Is there a solution to this problem?

Best regards,
Oskar

Comment: You write the plain js to class-instance conversion yourself. This process is often called ‘hydration’. (Look it up) This may be implemented as a static method (eg ‘hydrate’) of your book class for instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a good practise, but after retrieving the library object you can try:

```
retrievedData.onsuccess = function(e) {
    if (retrievedData.result) console.log(retrievedData);
    if (retrievedData.result) library = retrievedData.result.data;
    const fixedLibrary = library.map(book => Object.setPrototypeOf(book, Book.prototype))
    fixedLibrary.forEach(book => book.displayInfo());
}
```

Although, I would recommend you not using classes if you intend to store the instances in a database, but a module oriented approach...

Comment: OK. I'll consider the module oriented approach. But first I need to educate myself in this field. Could you please recommend me a publication or a book which explains this approach in the best way. Of course, if this is not a problem for you :)
Thanks in advance

Comment: If you tell me more about what are you trying to do(I understand it is some kind of API) I can recommend you some tutorials, as most of my knowledge comes from there and experience...

Comment: I'm trying to create an app for keeping track of user's book library. And right now I'm trying to add a functionality which allows storing data. I'm not ready for server-side programming so I'm looking for the best method of storing data locally.
If you want, you can check it out on my GitHub repository but I'm warning you it is a mess right now:
https://github.com/OskarGrzelak/MyLibrary
Everything is new for me :)

Comment: Hey! Are you able to elaborate why this is not a good practise? Thanks :)